# Polling via an IntentService and using AlarmManager

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, alarmmanager, intentservice

I am just having a hard time understanding the AlarmManager system, tied in with future notifications etc. I can't seem to get the AlarmManager to set alarms at the correct frequency.

I'm also unsure where I should actually create an alarm, and what type is most suited to my needs.

Updates are based on Preferences which will be detailed below.

---

### Launching the Service

When my application is launched, the service is called when a FragmentActivity is created. Within the onCreate(), I have the following:

```
Intent mServiceIntent = new Intent(this, ServiceUpdater.class);
if(startService(mServiceIntent)==null)
startService(mServiceIntent);
```

Lots of other stuff happens and fragments are shown ect, but this is essentially to ensure the service is running. Note, I also have it set to call the BroadcastReceiver on System startup.

### ServiceUpdater.class

```
public class ServiceUpdater extends IntentService{

    private SharedPreferences defaultPrefs;
    private SharedPreferences userPrefs;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    // Alarm Service
    private AlarmManager alarmManager;
    private PendingIntent alarmIntent;

    public ServiceUpdater() {
            super("MyService");
}

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

            defaultPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            userPrefs = getSharedPreferences("user", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


            long updateFrequency = (Long.parseLong(defaultPrefs.getString("updateFrequencyPref", "24")))*1000*60*60; 
            // in hours = 1000*60*60*'24'        

            long thirtySecondsAfterWake = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 30*1000; // 30 seconds after the device boots

            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, UpdateReceiver.class);
            alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, thirtySecondsAfterWake, updateFrequency, alarmIntent); 

            if(defaultPrefs.getBoolean("updatePref", true))
                    new Update().execute();
    }


    private class Update extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer>{
        private int newNumber;

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        newNumber= new HttpServices().getNewNumber(); 
        return newNumber;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer noJobs){
        if(newNumber > 0){ //userPrefs.getInt("oldNumber", 0)){
            editor = userPrefs.edit();
            editor.putInt("oldNumber", newNumber);
            editor.commit();
            if(!FragActivity.active)
                new MyNotif(getApplicationContext(), "NewData");
        }
    }

} // end Async
} // end service class
```

### UpdateReceiver.class

```
public class UpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent updater = new Intent(context, ServiceUpdater.class);
        context.startService(updater);
    }

}
```

### ---------------------

My guess is that when the alarm calls the Receiver, it creates a new Alarm, and then updates the old one, setting the next update time to be 30 seconds in the future; which explains why the HTTP request is happening (and I'm getting notifications every 30 seconds or so.

I want to ensure my alarm runs even when the application is not running.

My aim for this application is to do the following.

1. Run the App / or / On Phone Startup
2. Start a service that polls (e.g. Daily) a single Http Request
3. Regardless of the response, ensure the Polling happens again the following iteration timeframe
4. A notification will fire from onPostExecute based on the results of the polling

Where do I correctly set the Alarm so that it is not recreated every time the service is - but runs correctly even when the application isn't running?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but this is essentially to ensure the service is running

I have no idea why you are starting the service twice.

> ServiceUpdater.class

I have no idea why you are using an `AsyncTask` inside an `IntentService`. This is bad on several levels. `onHandleIntent()` is already called on a background thread, and I would expect your app to flat-out crash when trying to create an `AsyncTask` on a background thread. Just move all the background logic into `onHandleIntent()` (or methods called by `onHandleIntent()`).

> My guess is that when the alarm calls the Receiver, it creates a new Alarm, and then updates the old one, setting the next update time to be 30 seconds in the future; which explains why the HTTP request is happening (and I'm getting notifications every 30 seconds or so.

I have no idea why you are setting up a repeating alarm on every run.

> Where do I correctly set the Alarm so that it is not recreated every time the service is - but runs correctly even when the application isn't running?

Your code to set up the `AlarmManager` schedule needs to be executed:

- On the first run of your app (since you have not had an opportunity to set up the alarms yet)
- After the user force-stops your app from Settings (since your previously-scheduled alarms are wiped out)
- After a reboot (since your previously-scheduled alarms are wiped out)

A typical pattern for handling the first two is to keep track of when your alarm code last ran, such as in a `SharedPreference`. Then, either in a custom `Application` or in a likely entry point of your app (e.g., launcher activity), check the `SharedPreference` value for your last alarm run time:

- If there is no value, that means it's the first run of your app, so you schedule the alarms
- If there is a value, and it is significantly longer than your polling period, you assume that your app was force-stopped, and so you schedule the alarms
- Otherwise, there is a plausible value, so you assume that your alarms are working just fine

Handling the reboot scenario is a matter of running through your `AlarmManager` scheduling logic in response to an `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast.

Note that you are using `ELAPSED_REALTIME`, which means that the alarm will be delayed if the device is in sleep mode.

Also note that you are using `setInexactRepeating()`, which means that the alarm will go off sometime within the polling period, but not at a precise interval.

Comment: Thanks very much for that. I have moved the alarm to my MainActivity onCreate and set up a preference like you have suggested. Just testing it as we speak.

Comment: Mind having a look at my logic here whether to re-create the service?

-

if(!userPrefs.getBoolean("alarmSet", false) ||
       (userPrefs.getLong("alarmSetTime", 0) == 0 || 
        (userPrefs.getLong("alarmSetTime", 0)) < (System.currentTimeMillis() - ((Long.parseLong(defaultPrefs.getString("updateFrequencyPref", "24")))*1000*60*60))))
      setUpdateAlarm();

Comment: @shanehoban: I do not know why `updateFrequencyPref` is a string value instead of an `int` or `long`. Also, your algorithm would require `alarmSetTime` to be updated each time your `IntentService` runs, which means that `alarmSetTime` is an odd name IMHO (I'd use `alarmLastOccurred` or something like that). I also personally like to leave a bit of "fudge factor" on the duration that triggers resetting the alarms (e.g., add in a `1.5` factor in your multiplication chain), though that just may be my normal Murphy paranoia coming through.

Comment: Yeah I know it isn't ideal to have it as a String Value, but it works out better with the UI changes when changes are made in the preferences. Took that on board and included some fudge factor time; think you're right and it's clever. What I am wondering now, is; is it safe to just re-create a new alarm when the preferences are changed (i.e. when the user changes their update frequency preference?). I have extracted the alarm to a separate class, so I now call `new AlarmUpdater(this).setUpdateAlarm();` Would it be OK to just call this after preferences change?

Comment: @shanehoban: So long as you are using the same `Intent` structure, yes, that should be safe. It will cancel the existing alarm and replace it with the new one.

Comment: Is this still a valid way to implement polling in the background (even at sleep), or I have to use FCM instead? I have two projects currently which could benefit from mobile phone alarms and an interval around 10 mins (or at most 30 mins) would be fine for both. I try to avoid using external services like FCM if possible and all I need is playing a sound when the server says that things happened, so nothing fancy...

Comment: @inf3rno: "Is this still a valid way to implement polling in the background" -- no, sorry. This answer is from 2014. `WorkManager` is probably the best option for your desired interval, though bear in mind that Doze mode and app standby mean that nothing is guaranteed.